# How to view TF-IDF results?

Tags: python, tf-idf

I am looking at this example

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/predicting-movie-genres-nlp-multi-label-classification/

exactly at the line where using TF-IDF

```
# create TF-IDF features
xtrain_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(xtrain)
xval_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(xval)
```

When i try to view the results of xtrain_tfidf I get this message

```
xtrain_tfidf
Out[69]: 
<33434x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3494870 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I would like to see what does xtrain_tfidf have?

how can I view it?

Comment: Where do you see the error? It's just telling you that the result is a sparse matrix

Comment: ok, how to view the results in TFIDF?

Comment: The duplicate is related, but doesn't answer the question quite as asked. I find the answer here complimentary and worth having as an answer to this slightly different question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter (or rather IPython (or rather the Python REPL)) implicitly calls `xtrain_tfidf.__repr__()` when you evaluate the name of the variable. Using `print` calls `xtrain_tfidf.__str__()`, which is what you're looking for when you want to see the nonzero values in a sparse matrix:

```py
print(xtrain_tfidf)
```

If you want to print everything including zero-values, slowness and possible out-of-memory be darned, then try

```py
import numpy as np

with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf):
    print(xtrain_tfidf.toarray())
```